# Is there a way to have a shared 'Base Image' in Hyper-V?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-11, hyper-v

I don't know if my terminology is correct, but I want to create a base image for some of my Hyper-V instances. To be clear, I'm not asking how to create a gold image or template, but instead I want all of my virtual machines to point to this image and the build their individual changes on top of it.

To better understand, all of my virtual machines will have Microsoft Office (and some other software) installed on them along with Windows 11 taking up about 80 GB of disk space, but aside from that they will have their own software, files, backgrounds, settings, etc. The reason I want them to have a shared base image is I want to try to save some storage space on my host machine and they all have some overlapping required software. If I spin up two of these machines, then I save roughly 80 GB of space if they have a shared 'base'; If I spin up three of these machines, then I save roughly 160 GB, etc.

Is this even possible, does Hyper-V support this?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this would be possible since Hyper-V is a type 1 hypervisor and runs directly on the physical hardware. If it is possible, what if the "base" one crashed? Then all of the machines using it would crash. Please correct me if I'm not understanding your question properly.

Comment: first comment is incorrect.  What the OP wants is a differencing disk.  Create a base "parent" disk, then create the "differencing" child disks from it.  Ideally, you'd write protect the base "parent" image.  google " hyper-v differencing disks" and you'll find how-tos

Comment: @DrZoo `If it is possible, what if the "base" one crashed? Then all of the machines using it would crash.` True (assuming crash means corrupted), but that doesn't mean it would be impossible, let alone being related "type 1 hypervisor" whatsoever. (Besides, your concern does not go away even if all equals to one.)

Comment: You don't run the base OS.  It's just the "parent" it just serves as the base of the image.  Only the children VMs linked to parent are running.  Once you create a base parent image, you never make changes to or run it, as you'll corrupt any child images attached.

Comment: @essjae: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I just didn't know the term was "differencing disk".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the entire procedure before beginning.

Definitions:

**Base** or **parent** image:  this is the the original VM.  Once used for child images, this image should not be moved or modified in any way.

**Child** image: a VM made using a differencing disk and will inherit the installation of the base image.

When creating the VM in Hyper-V, use Gen 2 and disable checkpoints.   Differencing disks cannot be created if a VM has checkpoints.  Checkpoints are essentially limited versions differencing disks.
[image]

Set up the base image with everything needed.  Once the base disk is created it should be made read-only and not modifiable.  Without the base image, any child images created from it will be unusable.

**Changing/modifying the base image will affect any child images negatively and could result in a *complete loss of all the data in any child VMs*.**

All steps below, if not specified, are done using Hyper-V Manager.

Creating a child VM from your base image:

1. Shut down base VM. Locate your base VHDX file.  The location can be found by highlighting the VM in Hyper-V Manager, clicking **Settings**, and clicking on **Hard Drive**.  Note this location, as it will be needed in later steps.  Copy and pasting the image path into Notepad, is an option.
2. Click **New**, then click **Hard Disk...**  Click **Next** to begin the New Virtual Hard Disk Wizard.
3. Select **VHDX**, click **Next**.
4. Select **Differencing**, click **Next**.
5. Enter a Name for the child image...ex: *Win10-child01*. Click **Browse** if the default image location is not used.[image]
6. Click **Browse** and locate the base image
   [image]
7. Click **Finish**
   The new disk image *Win10-Child01* will be used for creating a new VM.

Create a new VM:

8. In Hyper-V Manager: Click **New** and then **Virtual Machine**
9. Click **Next**, enter the child VM name, ex: *Win10-Child01*, click **Next**.
10. Select **Generation 2**, click **Next**.
11. Select the same memory size as the base VM had and click **Next**
12. Select the network connection, and click **Next**.
13. Select **Use an existing virtual hard disk** and **Browse** to the location  of the ***child image*** created in step 5 above.  Click **Next**.
    [image]
14. Click **Finish**

If chaining child VMs, the child VM should have checkpoints disabled before starting.

Once complete, I recommend removing the base VM from Hyper-V Manager to prevent an accidental start of the VM.  Right-clicking the base VM and selecting **Delete** will remove the VM's configuration, but will not delete the virtual hard disks associated with the VM.

Considerations:  The child images are exact duplicates of the base image which could cause issues in some cases.  For example, if using the child VMs in a domain environment, additional steps, like sysprep, should be taken to provide the child with a unique identity.

Additional licensing may be needed for child VMs depending the the base OS licensing conditions.

Comment: One point of confusion. Do all virtual machines need to have checkpoints disabled, or only parents in the chain; Can I have checkpoints enabled on the final virtual machine child if it not being used as a parent itself?

Comment: Just the parent/base image, or any other image you'd want to make a differencing disk off of.